# why getBoundingClientRect gives different values in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Image control and I need to place some elements on top of the image control. when I used getBoundingClientRect() it is working in IE(7,8 and 9) but It is giving different values in Firefox and Chrome. Is there any other function available for getting the Bounding rectangle of an element ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Citation from old IE documentation for `getBoundingClientRect`: "In Microsoft® Internet Explorer 5, the window's upper-left is at 2,2 (pixels) with respect to the true client." This still seems to be valid.

In IE9 usage of `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>` "sets" the upper-left corner to it's right position (0,0).

As d4rkpr1nc3 answered, you can get those values by other methods, but the results depend on the used browser too. I think you'll need a slightly different approach to this problem. Check the code below, it might give you some ideas.

```
<DIV id="imagecontrol" style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:200px;">
  <DIV id="topleft" style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;left:0px;top:0px;"></DIV>
  <DIV id="topright" style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;right:0px;top:0px;"></DIV>
  <DIV id="bottomleft" style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;left:0px;bottom:0px;"></DIV>
  <DIV id="bottomright" style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;right:0px;bottom:0px;"></DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: how do you get ie8 to give the same values as chrome?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper The idea of my answer is, that you probably can't. The layout model is dfferent in different browsers, especially in old-ones like IE8. You can do math with the value though, but it's better to ask your own question about how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

The values maybe slightly different in different browsers but `getBoundingClientRect()` is still your best bet for performance and accuracy. The coordinates it returns are relative to the viewport rather than the document, however, so you'll need to account for that using scroll values on the window / document.

Here's a good blog post about this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/01/29/getting-absolute-coordinates-from-a-dom-element.aspx

David Mark is good on this stuff. Here's a tip of his from [comp.lang.javascript](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/comp.lang.javascript):

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.javascript/zWJaFM5gMIQ

Answer (score 3):

You could use offsets to do that, like this:

```
var top = element.offsetTop;
var left = element.offsetLeft;
var width = element.offsetWidth;
var height = element.offsetHeight;
var bottom = top + height;
var right = left + width;
```

Comment: Not really. For example, `getBoundingClientRect` takes into account CSS transformations.

Comment: Indeed no: offsetTop is the position relative to a positioned parent if there is one, so any parent with position:relative/fixed/absolute will affect the offset value ( versus the offset value from the domcument.body which is what we generally want)

Comment: This solved a problem for me where we were trying to use `range.getBoundingClient()` from a hidden iFrame and Firefox & IE were returning all zeros (0) for x/y/width/height.  @d4rkpr1nc3 thx!