# IE 8 width issue with decimal values

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have used two div element. The below structure I have used.

```
<div id="firstelement" style="width:681px; height:401px">
      <div id="secondelement" style="width:50%;height:50%;"></div>
</div>
```

I need to get the exact width("340.5px") of second div in IE8. How can I get it using JavaScript?

Tried like below

```
$("#getWidth").click(function(){
  var ele = document.getElementById("secondelement");
    var box = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
    alert("Width = "+ box.right - box.left); // Integer value returned.
});
```

Can you please give your suggestion to resolve this issue?

Comment: `$('#secondelement').width()` ???

Comment: @Tushar jquery will return the integer rounded values. I mean is there a way to get exact values with pixel in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rect = $("#secondelement")[0].getBoundingClientRect();

var width;
if (rect.width) {
  // `width` is available for IE9+
  width = rect.width;
  alert(width)
} else {
  // Calculate width for IE8 and below
  width = rect.right - rect.left;
  alert(width)
}
```

**DEMO:**  http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/7s6Lta50/

Comment: This will return 341 in IE8 which is not required one. I need to get the decimal values as i mentioned "340.5" in IE8.

Comment: This link might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230715/why-getboundingclientrect-gives-different-values-in-ie-and-firefox